# BF - Hardline - gun changes to hand weapon

Tags: battlefield-hardline

In BF Hardline, if you get close to a enemy the weapon changes to a hand weapon (bat, baton, ax etc...) automatically. Is there a way to disable this? There have been a number of times when an enemies car gets close and my weapon changes. Also happens when I am close to an enemy on foot and don't want to use a hand weapon.

Comment: What system?  I'm playing on the PS4 and have noticed several bugs and glitches along this line.

Comment: I'm on PlayStation 4

Comment: One thing I've seen is that every so often, the arrest animation glitches out.  The enemy will go from standing up to laying on the floor without the actual animation playing.

Answer (score 1):

I play On PS3 System And I have experienced the same bug.To Stop It from changing to a hand weapon press the triangle button before you approach and it should stop.